# Server Error in '/' application. Parameter name: sessionStateBehaviorResolver - Sitecore 9.3

Tags: sql-database, sitecore-mvc

I am having issues with the connection of `Sitecore` after I tried to connect `VS Studio 2019`. The `Solr` is running and my server seems fine. `Sitecore` was running just fine until I tried to build a connection into `Sitecore` using `VS Studio`. I copied the `web.config` and `global.asax`, `Sitecore` files into my `vs code` solution and built them onto the root web folder and that's when everything crashed.

````
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: sessionStateBehaviorResolver

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: sessionStateBehaviorResolver]    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName) +64    Sitecore.Owin.Extensions.AppBuilderExtensions.SetSessionStateBehaviorResolver(IAppBuilder app, SessionStateBehaviorResolver sessionStateBehaviorResolver) +54    Sitecore.Owin.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) +28

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0    System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +132    System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
+146    Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass12.<MakeDelegate>b__b(IAppBuilder builder) +93    Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<LoadImplementation>b__0(IAppBuilder builder) +224    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) +900    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +51  Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
+101    System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
+139    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +160    System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +587    System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +173    System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +255    System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +347

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +552    System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
+122    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +737```
````

Comment: Can you provide more clarification on this? How you are creating a connection between VS Studio and Sitecore. Do you want to use Sitecore Rocks by using this? Or anything else you are trying?

Comment: Yes, I used Sitecore rocks to build the connection and once the solution was published that's when Sitecore crash. I followed Sitecore's documentation for this instance https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/set-up-sitecore-and-visual-studio-for-development.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the document you are following is stating that you don't need to copy or publish your `Web.Config` to your `Sitecore` instance. See this as given in the document.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/set-up-sitecore-and-visual-studio-for-development.html

This is given in the section under the **Set up a Visual Studio Project** and point 4.

The `Web.config` file in the `Visual Studio` project is quite minimal, while the `Web.config` file in the `Sitecore` instance contains important settings. This step is to avoid that the file from `Visual Studio` overwrites the one in `Sitecore` when you publish.

In `Visual Studio`, in the Solution Explorer, right-click the `Web.config` file in the root of the project, and select Properties. Set the `Build Action` property to `None` and the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Do not copy`

So revert your `Web.Config` changes in the Sitecore and then try again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Sumit,, looking at the Web.config now and yes, I s what happended and the Web.config file was overwritten. Do you know how am I ablle to revert the web.config file? Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, you can get the web.config from your Sitecore Vanilla instance or we can say, extract your Sitecore package i.e. "Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (Setup XP0 Developer Workstation rev. 1.1.1-r4)" and open the folder and again extract "Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp", open folder and you will find the Sitecore instance. Get the config from there and use. Hope you like this.