# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: sessionStateBehaviorResolver

Tags: installation

Installed `Sitecore 10.1` using `SIF`. Sitecore installtion completed successfuly without any issue. When I tried to open Sitecore login page getting this issue.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: sessionStateBehaviorResolver
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: sessionStateBehaviorResolver

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: sessionStateBehaviorResolver]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName) +63
   Sitecore.Owin.Extensions.AppBuilderExtensions.SetSessionStateBehaviorResolver(IAppBuilder app, SessionStateBehaviorResolver sessionStateBehaviorResolver) +54
   Sitecore.Owin.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) +28
```

Can someone help in resolving this issue please?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check this one ? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31671/server-error-in-application-parameter-name-sessionstatebehaviorresolver

Comment: Before posting this issue, I saw your comment on the shared URL.. I have not changed anything. Just after installation I opened sitecore login page and saw this error. thanks Sumit.

Comment: Usually this happens when wrong web.config is deployed. I.e. Deployed cd web.config locally etc. Check redis connections line. Ensure correct topology packages were used. Replace web.config with vanilla one from OnPrem scwdp package.

Answer (score 0):

I have instlled sitecore 10.1 and it is working fine on my machine.Copy/download web.config and replace with your on local machine and see if it works for you.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oj1wNjzBzn4E-9arUpUEpsczxtEa_OCc/view?usp=sharing